# VBA: Counting rows in a table (list object)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some VBA in Excel that can take the name of a table (list object) as a parameter and return the number of rows.

The following works, but isn't allowing me to pass in a string with the table name.

```
MsgBox ([MyTable].Rows.Count)
```

The following gives the error:

> Object required

```
v_MyTable = "MyTable"
MsgBox (v_MyTable.Rows.Count)
```

The following gives the error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

```
v_MyTable_b = "[" & "MyTable" & "]"
MsgBox(v_MyTable_b.Rows.Count)
```

I also tried working with ListObjects, which I am new to. I get the error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable")
MsgBox(tbl.Rows.Count)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to go one level deeper in what you are retrieving.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable")
MsgBox tbl.Range.Rows.Count
MsgBox tbl.HeaderRowRange.Rows.Count
MsgBox tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Set tbl = Nothing
```

More information at:

[ListObject Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.aspx)
  [ListObject.Range Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.range.aspx)
  [ListObject.DataBodyRange Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193223.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
  [ListObject.HeaderRowRange Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.headerrowrange.aspx)

Comment: Note that if the table is empty, `tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` throws an error

Comment: Instead `tbl.listrows.count` can be used to get the number of rows even if the table is empty. This would not throw any error in a code

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
    Range("MyTable[#Data]").Rows.Count
```

You have to distinguish between a table which has either one row of data or no data, as the previous code will return "1" for both cases.
Use this to test for an empty table:

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("MyTable[#Data]"))
```

Comment: How does this improve on the accepted answer from over 1 year ago?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that @Jalal anwser was late for you, but I'm really glad he posted it!

Comment: `[#data]` can be omited. i.e. `Range("MyTable").Rows.Count` can be used. This is even better: `Range("MyTable").ListObject.ListRows.Count` as it will return 0 if the table has no rows (a variation of what @Kanike mentioned in his comment above).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Sub returnname(ByVal TableName As String)

MsgBox (Range("Table15").Rows.count)

End Sub
```

and call the function as below

```
Sub called()

returnname "Table15"

End Sub
```