# Determine if table is empty, then skip rest of macro

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is what I used to compare entries between two tabs on a worksheet. There is a helper column on the table object OpenComplaints labeled CCMS Notification. It searches for a match on the table object OpenQns. If there is no match it returns #N/A.

The purpose of this macro is to autofilter column CCMS Notification on table OpenComplaints for #N/A, then copy over the DataBodyRange and paste these results onto a third tab. It then deletes the entries from OpenComplaints that were copied over.

This all works great. However it breaks down if the table is empty. I want this to skip the macro if the table is empty. I've spent a few hours trying many examples from google and stackoverflow and I just can't seem to get any examples to work, so I apologize if this has been asked elsewhere but I can't seem to get other people's code to work. Currently, if the table is empty it selects the entire table (even when autofiltered) and then deletes the entries.

Ideally, I'd like to use as many structured references as possible as the risk of people adding or removing columns is high on this worksheet.

This is my code

```
Sub DeleteClosedQns()
'
' DeleteClosedQns Macro

If Range("D9").Value = "" Then
Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
response = MsgBox("Previous step is not marked as complete. Proceed?", vbYesNo)
If response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
End If

'Checks if the previous step was completed, as marked by a X.

Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").Select
Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "#N/A"
Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").DataBodyRange.Copy

' Sets AutoFilter to #N/A, then copies the table body

Sheets("YTD History Closed").Select
With activesheets
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("YTD History Closed").ListObjects("ClosedQns").Range.Columns(4).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
End With

Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

' Navigates to the History Closed tab, calculates the last row used
' Then pastes with special values

Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").Select
Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").DataBodyRange.ClearContents

' Selects the entries that have been copied over, then deletes them

If Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").ShowAutoFilter Then
    Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").Range.AutoFilter
End If

' Removes the data filter

Sheets("Instructions").Select
Range("D10", "D10").Value = "X"
' Marks the step as complete with an X

End Sub
```

edit: @soulshined. I'm glad it's just simple logic validation. However I've mentioned that I'm having trouble with it. Please don't disregard my question just because it's simple to you.

@bigben sorry yes, I'm copying only the filtered data. Then later deleting the filtered data. It only copies the entire range if there are no results from autofilter, which is an error I'm trying to avoid.

I tried CountA with the following test code
     Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "#N/A"

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("OpenComplaints[CCMS Notification]")) > 0 Then
MsgBox ("> 0")
End If
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("OpenComplaints[CCMS Notification]")) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("Empty")
End If
```

It's not actually telling me if a filtered table is empty. It seems to count even hidden columns, as my table OpenComplaints has no "#N/A" entries and is empty when I apply that filter. XlCellTypeVisible doesn't appear to work with CountA.

Thank you for showing me that other question, however the fundamental question is not a duplicate.

Comment: if you want to see if a table is empty just count how many rows it has, and per skipping the macro thats just simple logic validation. I will mark as duplicate because the fundamental question is the same. See the link attached, and make sure you read some comments as they are helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Counting rows in a table (list object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639474/vba-counting-rows-in-a-table-list-object)

Comment: How is your filtering the table and then copying the `DataBodyRange` working as you say it is? Sounds like you only want to copy the visible cells after filtered - but you're copying the **entire** `DataBodyRange`... (?). Same goes for clearing the `DataBodyRange` at the end.

Comment: @soulshined I'd suggest OP use `WorksheetFunction.CountA` instead of counting rows - the table could have no data but still be formatted as a bunch of blank rows. Your referenced question is still helpful in this regard.

Comment: You bring up a valid point @BigBen , but thats included in the link I provided as a possible solution. And that's why I mentioned reading comments :P

Comment: My reply was apparently too large for a comment. I've edited my post instead @soulshined